# Header Doesn't Stretch Properly

Tags: css, alignment, stretch

I have this problem when I collapse my webpage, the header shrinks instead of staying stretched across the entire page.

[image]

In this situation, I really have no idea what code to post along with it. I've tried various ways to fix it and nothing seems to work. Does anyone know what is going on when this happens? Here is my header HTML and CSS:

```css
#header {
  background-color: #C67171;
  width: 100%;
}
#headtop {
  text-align: right;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 58px;
}
a.nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 58px;
  padding: 20px 12px;
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="headtop">
    <a href="about.html" class="nav">About</a>
    <a href="gallery.html" class="nav">Gallery</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

That's pretty much it for the styling though, any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT**
Picture explaining the outcome of the code.

[image]

This is what the page looks like right now. This is how I want it to look. But for some reason, I keep getting the problem that I have in the picture above when I collapse the page. I don't want to links to stretch to the outside of my page, that does not fix my problem.

Comment: What browser are you testing in?

Comment: Currently, I am testing it in Chrome.

Comment: @TylerDood I cannot recreate this problem.

Comment: @Ruddy Does it work when you run the code snippet?

Comment: change `width: 1000px;` to `width: 100%;` in `#headtop`.

Comment: @TylerDood It works exactly how you coded it, the header is always 100% width of the window. The reason you get the extra bit on the end (when you scroll) is because you have `#headtop` set to `width:1000px;`. To get rid of that set it to `width: 100%;`.

Comment: I don't want the links to stretch to the outside of the page with the header. That is why I added a second div so I could set the background to stretch 100% across the page and then set the foreground div to have a width of 1000px so I can center it and move the text to the right of that div.

Comment: @TylerDood Look at my answer, that fixes the problem. You not asking for more but didn't really explain it well enough for me to work off of it. At the end of the day, we have fixed your problem now so you can move on with your project and find another way to do whatever you have trying to do. If you have any more questions feel free to ask.

Comment: @Ruddy I apologize for my confusion in explaining the question, but your answer is not what I am trying to achieve. I posted a picture and another description as an edit above.

Comment: @TylerDood I think you will find that my answer does answer the question of "Header Doesn't Stretch Properly". Anything more than that is just me being nice, what do you want the links to do when the page gets smaller? And by your edit you fail to see the problem even tho it is explained in my answer.

Comment: @TylerDood So you want something like this? [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mctodtd0/)

Comment: @Ruddy That is correct. That is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: @TylerDood If you could now mark the answer as correct that would be great.

Comment: I added the same code into my page and I had the same problem with the whitespace.

Comment: @TylerDood Well you clearly didn't give us all of the relevant code then, as you can see the fiddle is working correctly. I have already done more than your question requires so I will not be following this up anymore.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69402/discussion-between-tyler-dood-and-ruddy).

Answer (score 0):

Try this  [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/owjLmLag/)

```css
#header {
  background-color: #C67171;
  display:inline-block;
}
#headtop {
  text-align: right;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 58px;
}
a.nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 58px;
  padding: 20px 12px;
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="headtop">
    <a href="about.html" class="nav">About</a>
    <a href="gallery.html" class="nav">Gallery</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This did not work, it had the same output as the original code.

Comment: @TylerDood It is working fine for me i will show you a screen shot in a few moments

Comment: Strange. What is the outcome when you run the code snippet? To be certain, this only happens when the page is collapse past a certain point.

Comment: It works properly in the fiddle, but when I add it to my page and run it in the code snippet, it still has the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is when the window is showing greater than 1000px on screen you're page seems to work. When you make it smaller the header will shrink thanks to `width: 100%;`.

But as we get smaller the div `#headtop` will stay the same size `width: 1000px;`. So the header will get smaller but the child element (`#headtop`) will still be big causing the scrolling you are seeing.

```css
#header {
  background-color: #C67171;
  width: 100%;
}
#headtop {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 58px;
}
a.nav {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  line-height: 58px;
  padding: 20px 12px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <div id="headtop">
    <a href="about.html" class="nav">About</a>
    <a href="gallery.html" class="nav">Gallery</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Here is how you keep the links away from the sides (look at comments for more on that). Give `#headertop` a max width and then give it a width of 80% or however much you want the gap to have.

[JSFIddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mctodtd0/)